# How to use sort and awk command to sort dates in the 4th column of a file

Tags: sorting, awk

I have the following file called st.txt:

```
Item    Type    Amount  Date
Petrol  expense -160    2020-01-23
Electricity expense -200    2020-03-24
Electricity expense -200    2020-04-24
Trim line   expense -50 2020-05-30
Martha Burns    income  150 2021-03-11
Highbury shops  income  300 2021-03-14
```

I want to sort the data by date and print all data except the first line.
The following command works:

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR>1{print $4"\t"$1"\t"$2"\t"$3}' st.txt | sort -t"-" -n -k1 -k2 -k3
```

The output then is:

```
2020-01-23  Petrol  expense -160
2020-03-24  Electricity expense -200
2020-04-24  Electricity expense -200
2020-05-30  Trim line   expense -50
2021-03-11  Martha Burns    income  150
2021-03-14  Highbury shops  income  300
```

How can I write this command so I do not have to rearrange the columns so the date field remains at $4?
I tried the following but it does not work:

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR>1{print $0}' st.txt | sort -t"-" -n -k 4,1 -k 4,2 -k 4,3
```

The dates are not sorted with this command.

The output should be:

```
Petrol expense  -160    2020-01-23
Electricity expense -200    2020-03-24
Electricity expense -200    2020-04-24
Trim line   expense -500    2020-05-30
Martha Burns    income      150 2021-03-11
Highbury shops  income      300 2021-03-14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the fields in your input file are tab-separated as your code suggests they are:

```
$ tail -n +2 file | sort -t$'\t' -k4
Petrol  expense -160    2020-01-23
Electricity     expense -200    2020-03-24
Electricity     expense -200    2020-04-24
Trim line       expense -50     2020-05-30
Martha Burns    income  150     2021-03-11
Highbury shops  income  300     2021-03-14
```

Comment: Why the $ after -t?   sort -t$

Comment: The `$'\t'` is a bashism to specify the tab character. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

Comment: And if you have a *really* old shell, you can use decorate, sort, undecorated pattern with `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR>1{print $4, $0}' file | sort | cut  -f 2-`

Comment: @dawg with GNU sort 8.26 in bash 4.4.12(3) on cygwin, which I'm using, `sort -t '\t' -k4` fails with `sort: multi-character tab ‘\\t’`.

Comment: Hmm: That is interesting. MacOS and BSD work fine that way...

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk:

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR>1{a[$4]=$0} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; for(i in a){print a[i]}}' file
```

Output:

```
Petrol  expense -160    2020-01-23
Electricity     expense -200    2020-03-24
Electricity     expense -200    2020-04-24
Trim line       expense -50     2020-05-30
Martha Burns    income  150     2021-03-11
Highbury shops  income  300     2021-03-14
```

Comment: That would fail if 2 lines had the same date. `a[$4]=$0` needs to be `a[$4]=($4 in a ? a[$4] ORS : "") $0` or similar.

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes, since each row has its own date, I did not consider this case.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\t/,"\\t")} 1' file
Item\tType\tAmount\tDate
Petrol\texpense\t-160\t2020-01-23
Electricity\texpense\t-200\t2020-03-24
Electricity\texpense\t-200\t2020-04-24
Trim line\texpense\t-50\t2020-05-30
Martha Burns\tincome\t150\t2021-03-11
Highbury shops\tincome\t300\t2021-03-14
```

You can either use [Decorate / Sort / Undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) pattern with POSIX awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR>1{print $4, $0}' file | sort | cut  -f 2-
```

Or use a proper CSV parser set to use a `\t` instead of a comma. Ruby is the easiest:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
options={:col_sep=>"\t", :headers=>true, :return_headers=>true}
data=CSV.parse($<.read, **options).to_a
header=data.shift.to_csv(**options)
data.sort_by{|r| r[3]}.each{|r| puts r.to_csv(**options)}
' file
```

Either prints:

```
Petrol  expense -160    2020-01-23
Electricity expense -200    2020-03-24
Electricity expense -200    2020-04-24
Trim line   expense -50 2020-05-30
Martha Burns    income  150 2021-03-11
Highbury shops  income  300 2021-03-14
```