# AWK: sums problematic in awk table transform script

Tags: awk

I have the following file:

```
cat st_in.txt 
2015-01-01  2   A   FI
2015-02-03  4   B   VI
2015-03-01  6   A   FI
2015-01-08  -4  C   VE
2016-01-05  -3  B   VE
2016-02-03  -1  D   FE
2016-04-01  -2  B   FE
2016-06-13  -5  D   VE
2017-01-01  2   A   VI
2017-02-03  3   A   VI
2017-02-04  8   C   FI
2017-01-05  -1  B   FE
```

And want to transform it like this:

```
        2015    2016    2017

A       8.00    0.00    0.00
C       0.00    0.00    8.00
sumFI   8.00    0.00    8.00

A       0.00    0.00    5.00
B       4.00    0.00    0.00
sumVI   4.00    0.00    5.00

sumI    12.00   0.00    13.00

B       0.00    -2.00   -1.00
D       0.00    -1.00   0.00
sumFE   0.00    -3.00   -1.00

B       0.00    -3.00   0.00
C      -4.00    0.00    0.00
D       0.00    -5.00   0.00
sumVE   -4.00   -8.00   0.00

sumE    -4.00   -11.00  -1.00

net     8.00    -11.00  12.00
```

To do that I have written the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
BEGIN {
        OFS = "\t"
}

{
        yr = substr($1, 1, 4)
        sub(/-.*/, "", $1)
        minYr = (NR == 1 || $1 < minYr ? $1 : minYr)
        maxYr = (NR == 1 || $1 > maxYr ? $1 : maxYr)
        H[$4][$3]
        W[yr][$4][$3] += $2
        yT[$1] += $2
        val[$1][$4] += $2
}

END {
        for (yr = minYr; yr <= maxYr; yr++) {
                printf "%s%s", OFS, yr
        }
        print ""
        print ""
        for (cT in H) {
                for (c in H[cT]) {
                        printf c, OFS
                        for (yr = minYr; yr <= maxYr; yr++) {
                                printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, W[yr][cT][c]
                        }
                        print ""
                }
                printf "sum" cT, OFS
                for (yr = minYr; yr <= maxYr; yr++) {
                        printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, val[yr][cT]
                }
                print ""
                print ""
                if (cT == "VI") {
                        printf "sumI", OFS
                        for (yr = minYr; yr <= maxYr; yr++) {
                                printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, W[yr][cT][c]
                        }
                } else if (cT == "VE") {
                        printf "sumE", OFS
                        for (yr = minYr; yr <= maxYr; yr++) {
                                printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, W[yr][cT][c]
                        }
                }
                print ORS
        }
        printf "net"
        for (yr = minYr; yr <= maxYr; yr++) {
                printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, yT[yr]
        }
        print ""
}
' "${@:--}"
```

Which prints the following:

```
./trans1 st_in.txt 
    2015    2016    2017

A   8.00    0.00    0.00
C   0.00    0.00    8.00
sumFI   8.00    0.00    8.00



A   0.00    0.00    5.00
B   4.00    0.00    0.00
sumVI   4.00    0.00    5.00

sumI    4.00    0.00    0.00

B   0.00    -2.00   -1.00
D   0.00    -1.00   0.00
sumFE   0.00    -3.00   -1.00



B   0.00    -3.00   0.00
C   -4.00   0.00    0.00
D   0.00    -5.00   0.00
sumVE   -4.00   -8.00   0.00

sumE    0.00    -5.00   0.00

net 8.00    -11.00  12.00
```

I am not worried about the formatting here. The console printout is similar to the target. But what I am struggling with is to get the correct sums for sumI (sumFI + sumVI) and sumE(sumFE + sumVE). Can someone please help with that?

---

EDIT by Ed Morton to provide meaningful data types and variable names, assuming the OPs current data is column types of `Date Amount Item Type` as it was in [their first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70558840/1745001):

```
$ cat trans1
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
}

{
    date   = $1
    amount = $2
    item   = $3
    type   = $4

    year = substr(date, 1, 4)
    minYear = (NR == 1 || year < minYear ? year : minYear)
    maxYear = (NR == 1 || year > maxYear ? year : maxYear)

    types_items[type][item]
    yearsTypesItems2amounts[year][type][item] += $2
    years2amounts[year]                       += $2
    yearsTypes2amounts[year][type]            += $2
}

END {
    for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, year
    }
    print ""
    print ""
    for (type in types_items) {
        for (item in types_items[type]) {
            printf item, OFS
            for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
                printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, yearsTypesItems2amounts[year][type][item]
            }
            print ""
        }
        printf "sum" type, OFS
        for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
            printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, yearsTypes2amounts[year][type]
        }
        print ""
        print ""
        if (type == "VI") {
            printf "sumI", OFS
            for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
                printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, yearsTypesItems2amounts[year][type][item] # <--- NOTE: item unset here
            }
        } else if (type == "VE") {
            printf "sumE", OFS
            for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
                printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, yearsTypesItems2amounts[year][type][item] # <--- NOTE: item unset here
            }
        }
        print ORS
    }
    printf "net"
    for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
        printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, years2amounts[year]
    }
    print ""
}
' "${@:--}"
```

See the "NOTE"s above where by just doing this renaming exercise it became obvious where some bugs are (looks like you were using the wrong array and should be using `yearsTypes2amounts[year][type]` instead of `yearsTypesItems2amounts[year][type][item]`).

Comment: I fixed the indenting of your code for you by running it through GNU awk as `awk -o- 'script'`. Your code had strange/missing indenting, etc. that made the control flow of the program very hard to see. Going forward please see the `gawk -o-` pretty-printing output for a good example of how to structure your code legibly before posting questions.

Comment: for the `sum/sumI/sumE` outputs I see these `W[yr][cT][c]` references ... where is the `c` coming from? the only place I see `c` being populated is a `for` loop earlier in the code ... but these `W[yr][cT][c]` references are outside of that loop

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo markp-fuso. In that case net actually works. I have changed in the script

Comment: yes I have done that.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Unfortunately when I run awk -0- 'trans1' I only get: ```trans1 {
 print
}``` Same in awkprof.out

Comment: markp-fuso, c=$3. I am not sure what to use in place of W[yr][cT][c]. I left it there as everything else I tried did not work. Sorry but I find arrays of arrays hard to grasp.

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to solve sumVE, sumVI, sumFE and sumFI. I have updated the script and the output file to reflect the changes. The only thing I can't solve now is sumI and sumE.

Comment: The other option I see for your script is simply collect the data as a single rule and then do all the post-processing in the `END` rule. You can collect the data with `{split ($1, a, "-"); sum[a[1],$4,$3] += $2 }` and then separate and process the indexes in several different ways. You can loop over `sum` (e.g. `for (i in sum)`) and then split the index into an array of the parts with `split (i, b, SUBSEP)` and go from there.

Comment: when you write sum[a[1]... what does the 1 in a mean?

Comment: @ChristianHick Regarding [`when I run awk -0-`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71105118/awk-sums-problematic-in-awk-table-transform-script#comment125694015_71105118) - `-O` (upper case) as you used is not the same as `-o` (lower case) as I used. Case matters in options to any tool. Also, `trans1` is the name of a file that contains a **shell** script that **calls awk** - the **awk** script is the part between the single quotes in `awk 'script' file`, you can't call awk to interpret a shell script. To pretty-print your awk script replace `awk` with `awk -o-` inside the shell script.

Comment: @ChristianHick Regarding [`what does the 1 in a mean?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71105118/awk-sums-problematic-in-awk-table-transform-script#comment125698394_71105118) - I'm pretty surprised you're asking that given how much code you have using arrays but anyway: `a[1]` is the first entry in the array `a[]`. So if you do `split("foo-bar",a,"-")` then `a[1]` is the string `foo` and `a[2]` is the string `bar`.

Comment: Regarding all your recent questions - one of the problems in trying to help you is that it's hard to tell what your data represents and hard to tell what the variables in your code represent and so hard to figure out how they should be used. For example you have 4 columns of input. $1 is clearly a date but what are the other 3 fields? In your code you use `H[$4][$3]` so `$3` is something related to `$4` and you've used `height` before so maybe $3 is a height of something stored in $4? But then the value of $3 is a letter, not a number so that doesn't make sense.

Comment: And then you have `W[yr][$4][$3] += $2`and I expect `W` means width or weight but which is it and then that means you're adding whatever is stored in $2 (the only actual number in your data) to THAT so how can you have width or weight AND height in data that only has 1 numeric value? Then you have variables named `c` and `cT` - what the heck do THEY represent? It;s vastly easier to write code (and for us to help you with your code if you/we know what your input data values mean and you use meaningful variable names in your code (see previous answers for my attempts to understand your data).

Comment: Here's some naming guidelines for code that's longer than a couple of expressions: When naming a scalar variable name it using 3+ chars based on just **what** data it contains. When naming an array do the same but now you have 2 types of "contains" - the index and the value. If the array is a mapping from indices of type `foo` to values of type `bar` then name it `foos2bars[foo] = bar` (note the plurals) and then use it like `for (foo in foos2bars) bar=foos2bars[foo]` (note the singulars).

Comment: If your array maps multiple types of indices to a scalar value then include the type names (abbreviated if still clear) in the array name, e.g. `hwls2vols[height][width][lgth] = vol` and then `for (height in hwls2vols) for (width in hwls2vols[height]) etc.`. If your array contains a set of related values then use `_` instead of `2` in the array name, e.g. `foos_bars[foo][bar]` would contain the set of `bar`s associated with every `foo`. Hope that makes sense. Note that the array name parts are always plural and so when we access the individual indices or values as singular the code makes sense

Comment: You don't always need to follow those guidelines, I often don't as long as my codes clear and simple otherwise, but if you're struggling with your code s you are then following them will help you (and us) make sense of what your data represents and what you're trying to do with your code and so make debugging and enhancement vastly easier than if you don't follow those guidelines. Providing column names for your input data would be a great start to understanding it and your code.

Comment: I just looked back at [your very first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70558840/1745001) and I see in that one you had column headers of `Item    Type    Amount  Date`, it looks like it's just the order of the columns that was apparently different. Is that still what you have in your current question - `Date Amount Item Type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing to use GNU awk for arrays of arrays and assuming the OPs current data is column types of `Date Amount Item Type` as it was in [your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70558840/1745001):

```
$ cat trans1
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
}

{
    date   = $1
    amount = $2
    item   = $3
    type   = $4

    year = substr(date, 1, 4)
    minYear = (NR == 1 || year < minYear ? year : minYear)
    maxYear = (NR == 1 || year > maxYear ? year : maxYear)

    cat = substr(type,2)
    ctiys2amounts[cat][type][item][year] += amount
}

END {
    for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, year
    }
    print ORS
    for (cat in ctiys2amounts) {
        delete catSum
        for (type in ctiys2amounts[cat]) {
            delete typeSum
            for (item in ctiys2amounts[cat][type]) {
                printf "%s", item
                for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
                    amount = ctiys2amounts[cat][type][item][year]
                    printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, amount
                    typeSum[year] += amount
                }
                print ""
            }
            printf "sum%s", type
            for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
                printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, typeSum[year]
                catSum[year] += typeSum[year]
            }
            print ORS
        }
        printf "sum%s", cat
        for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
            printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, catSum[year]
            yearSum[year] += catSum[year]
        }
        print ORS
    }
    printf "net"
    for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
        printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, yearSum[year]
    }
    print ""
}
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./trans1 st_in.txt
        2015    2016    2017

B       0.00    -2.00   -1.00
D       0.00    -1.00   0.00
sumFE   0.00    -3.00   -1.00

B       0.00    -3.00   0.00
C       -4.00   0.00    0.00
D       0.00    -5.00   0.00
sumVE   -4.00   -8.00   0.00

sumE    -4.00   -11.00  -1.00

A       8.00    0.00    0.00
C       0.00    0.00    8.00
sumFI   8.00    0.00    8.00

A       0.00    0.00    5.00
B       4.00    0.00    0.00
sumVI   4.00    0.00    5.00

sumI    12.00   0.00    13.00

net     8.00    -11.00  12.00
```

Comment: Thanks Ed. The naming conventions in your comments are indeed extremely helpful. I do have a question with regards to this script though. I don't understand the purpose of "delete catSum" and "delete typeSum"? Especially as they have not been declared, thus what is there to delete and what for? The other issue which I may have to put in a seperate post is how to sort the output so I have the following order: sumVI, sumFI, sum I, sumVE, sumFE, sumE, net.

Comment: The deletes reset the counts stored in those arrays to zero at each iteration of the applicable loop so the counts for the first "type" aren't included in the counts for the 2nd "type", etc.. Try commenting out those statements and compare the results you get to the results with them in place. Yes, that would be a new question.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I am not understanding what 
```typeSum[year] += amount```
```catSum[year] += typeSum[year]```
```yearSum[year] += catSum[year]```purpose is. I know if I comment them out the result is garbeled.

Comment: No problem. `typeSum[year] += amount` accumulates the year-by-year sums of amounts for the "type" whose `for (type in ...` loop you're currently in. `catSum[year] += amount` accumulates the year-by-year sums of amounts for the "cat" whose `for (cat in ...` loop you're currently in. That's how you can later print a summary for each `year` for each `type` and for each `year` for each `cat`. Does that help any? You can run gawk in debug mode (see the man page) to see values changing and/or add print statements to manually trace them if that'd help.