# Awk: Formatting the order of table data in awk script

Tags: awk

I have the following output file. Please note that this data is dynamic, so there could be more or less years and many more categories A,B,C,D...:

```
    2015    2016    2017

EX

FE
B   0.00    -2.00   -1.00
D   0.00    -1.00   0.00
sumFE   0.00    -3.00   -1.00

VE
B   0.00    -3.00   0.00
C   -4.00   0.00    0.00
D   0.00    -5.00   0.00
sumVE   -4.00   -8.00   0.00

sumE    -4.00   -11.00  -1.00

IN

FI
A   8.00    0.00    0.00
C   0.00    0.00    8.00
sumFI   8.00    0.00    8.00

VI
A   0.00    0.00    5.00
B   4.00    0.00    0.00
sumVI   4.00    0.00    5.00

sumI    12.00   0.00    13.00

net 8.00    -11.00  12.00
```

I am trying to format it like this.

```
    2015    2016    2017

IN

VI
A   0.00    0.00    5.00
B   4.00    0.00    0.00
sumVI   4.00    0.00    5.00

FI
A   8.00    0.00    0.00
C   0.00    0.00    8.00
sumFI   8.00    0.00    8.00

sumI    12.00   0.00    13.00

EX

VE
B   0.00    -3.00   0.00
C   -4.00   0.00    0.00
D   0.00    -5.00   0.00
sumVE   -4.00   -8.00   0.00

FE
B   0.00    -2.00   -1.00
D   0.00    -1.00   0.00
sumFE   0.00    -3.00   -1.00

sumE    -4.00   -11.00  -1.00

net 8.00    -11.00  12.00
```

I have tried the following script as a start:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
awk '

BEGIN{FS="\t"}

3>NR {print "D" $0}

$1 ~ /^I$/,$1 ~ /^sumI$/ {
        print
}

$1 ~ /^E$/,$1 ~ /^sumE$/{
        print
}

$1 ~ /net/ {print ORS $0}

' "${@:--}"
```

The script would go a long way in replacing all I data for E data however the execution order is not preserved and the I block is printed out last. Can someone please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably be easier to modify the originating code to use [GNU awk's predefined array scanning orders](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html). The key objective is to switch the scanning order (`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`) just prior to the associated `for (index in array)` loop.

Adding four lines of code (see `# comments`) to what I'm guessing is the [originating code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71112364):

```
...
END {
    for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, year
    }
    print ORS
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"                           # sort cat == { I | E } in descending order
    for (cat in ctiys2amounts) {
        printf "%s\n\n",(cat=="I") ? "IN" : "EX"                    # print { IN | EX }
        delete catSum
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"                       # sort type == { VI | FI } || { VE | FE } in descending order
        for (type in ctiys2amounts[cat]) {
            print type
            delete typeSum
            PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"                    # sort item == { A | B | C | D } in ascending order
            for (item in ctiys2amounts[cat][type]) {
                printf "%s", item
                for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
                    amount = ctiys2amounts[cat][type][item][year]
                    printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, amount
                    typeSum[year] += amount
                }
                print ""
            }
....
```

This generates:

```
        2015    2016    2017

IN

VI
A       0.00    0.00    5.00
B       4.00    0.00    0.00
sumVI   4.00    0.00    5.00

FI
A       8.00    0.00    0.00
C       0.00    0.00    8.00
sumFI   8.00    0.00    8.00

sumI    12.00   0.00    13.00

EX

VE
B       0.00    -3.00   0.00
C       -4.00   0.00    0.00
D       0.00    -5.00   0.00
sumVE   -4.00   -8.00   0.00

FE
B       0.00    -2.00   -1.00
D       0.00    -1.00   0.00
sumFE   0.00    -3.00   -1.00

sumE    -4.00   -11.00  -1.00

net     8.00    -11.00  12.00
```